# why performance values for passive aggressive model changing every time?

Tags: machine-learning-model, model-evaluations, performance

i havq question, that am a little confused about PassiveAggressive performance values after i fitted tf-idf vectorization on it(bigram and trigram), the values are changed every time i run the code even i try to shutdown my laptop? the other model performance values were constant, can any one tell me why is that happening?

```
#Build machine learning model
# 1- Multinomunal Naive Bayes for Bigram&Trigram:
mnb_tf_bigram=MultinomialNB()
mnb_tf_bigram.fit(tfidf_train_2, y_train)
mnb_tf_trigram=MultinomialNB()
mnb_tf_trigram.fit(tfidf_train_3,y_train)

#passive aggressive classifire for Bigram&Trigram:
pass_tf_bigram=PassiveAggressiveClassifier()
pass_tf_bigram.fit(tfidf_train_2,y_train)
pass_tf_trigram=PassiveAggressiveClassifier()
pass_tf_trigram.fit(tfidf_train_3,y_train)

pred_mnb2 = mnb_tf_bigram.predict(tfidf_test_2)
acc= accuracy_score(y_test,pred_mnb2)
prec = precision_score(y_test, pred_mnb2)
rec = recall_score(y_test,pred_mnb2)
f1 = f1_score(y_test,pred_mnb2)
roc= roc_auc_score(y_test,pred_mnb2)

model_results = pd.DataFrame([['Multinoinal Naive Bayes- Bigram', acc,prec,rec,f1,roc]], 
            columns = ['Model','Accuracy', 'Precision','Sensitivity', 'F1-score','ROC'])
model_results

# now we will compare with other models
pred_mnb3= mnb_tf_trigram.predict(tfidf_test_3)     
pred_pass2 = pass_tf_bigram.predict(tfidf_test_2)
pred_pass3= pass_tf_trigram.predict(tfidf_test_3)

models = {
    'Multinominal Naive Bayes-Trigram' : pred_mnb3,
    'Passive Aggressive-Bigram' : pred_pass2,
    'passive Aggressive-Trigram' : pred_pass3
}

models= pd.DataFrame(models)
for column in models:
        acc= accuracy_score(y_test,models[column])
        prec= precision_score(y_test,models[column])
        rec= recall_score (y_test,models[column])
        f1= f1_score (y_test,models[column])
        roc= roc_auc_score (y_test,models[column])
        results = pd.DataFrame ([[column, acc,prec,rec,f1,roc]], 
                                columns = ['Model','Accuracy', 'Precision','Sensitivity', 'F1-score','ROC'])
        model_results = model_results.append(results, ignore_index = True)

model_results
```

this is the 1st output:
[image]

and this is the 2nd try after shutdown the laptop:

[image]